# My JsonObjectRequest POST Request not working?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-volley

I am trying to populate a Spinner using data from MySQL data base.

```java
public void getData() {
    /*To add parameters & values for the request*/
    Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < > ();
    params.put("Email", sessionemail);

    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);

    /*Create ArrayList to store vehicle_id to later get vehicle data from DB Query*/
    ArrayList < String > vehicleid = new ArrayList < > ();
    ArrayList < String > tagList = new ArrayList < > ();

    /*Initialize Json Object Request*/
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, parameters, response - > {
        try {
            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("tags");
            Log.d(String.valueOf(jsonArray), "JSON DATA");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String tag = jsonObject.optString("Tag");
                String vehicle = jsonObject.optString("Vehicle_Id");
                tagList.add(tag);
                vehicleid.add(vehicle);
                tagidAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < > (Alert.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tagList);
                tagidAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                tagSpinner.setAdapter(tagidAdapter);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, Throwable::getStackTrace);

    /*Adding request to the queue*/
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

The below is the data I get from my PHP by doing a GET request:

```json
{
    "tags": [{
        "Tag": "W1C6EZY583DB2907X4A",
        "Vehicle_Id": "4"
    }, {
        "Tag": "6QZL43YEWR6IMMFUING",
        "Vehicle_Id": "6"
    }, {
        "Tag": "STK6WQ8ONDOUMEFSGQF",
        "Vehicle_Id": "17"
    }, {
        "Tag": "93RPHOC8M2AAQ2P2TUX",
        "Vehicle_Id": "72"
    }, {
        "Tag": "UH31KR4F6EFGHJ33S82",
        "Vehicle_Id": "73"
    }]
}
```

So basically what I need is to insert the "Tag" values into the Spinner, but for some reason when I get to the jsonObjectRequest the request fails.

Comment: Simplify your problem: first, try this without all that JSON processing: hardcode an object with the data that _should_ work, and try your code. Does it work? Cool, then the problem is not with `JsonObjectRequest` but your payload creation code. Does it not work? Cool, the problem has nothing to do with your payload creation work, so there's no reason to include it in your question. To that end, always remember to try to form a [mcve], not "for us" but because going through that exercise almost always makes you find the problem on your own, and if not you have focused code to ask about.

Comment: please share you manifest also !

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is to your issue, but I did notice an error in your use of `Log.d`. The tag needs to come first in the method call, i.e. `Log.d(tag, message)`. I seem to recall there is a character limit on the tag, which may mean this method will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to StringRequest and this fixed my issue.

```
    StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String tag = jsonObject.optString("Tag");
                            String vehicle = jsonObject.optString("Vehicle_Id");
                            tagList.add(tag);
                            vehicleid.add(vehicle);
                            tagidAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Alert.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tagList);
                            tagidAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            tagSpinner.setAdapter(tagidAdapter);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
```